# To B or not 2 B

Tags: neologisms

I am far from being a doctrinaire stickler opposing all neologisms; Twitter alerts one to the merit of abbreviations like "2" for "too", "4" for "for" etc. But many new usages fail to gain my assent. One of these is the abbreviation "to" for "too", as in: "*It is **to** bad she couldn't get to the party*".

Can anyone trace the history of this usage? I have only noticed it quite recently. Is it a passing fad?

Comment: perhaps <em>neologism</em> is inaccurate. can anyone offer a more precise term for a word that already exists being used in a new way?

Comment: How about the lower case first person pronoun and in your case all lower case? That bothers me even more

Comment: I think this is too subjective. How can we distinguish people who simply can't spell from those who've made a conscious decision to settle for the two-letter form ***to*** when they actually mean ***too***? Do we even *know* that there actually are people at all who fall into that second category?

Comment: Your rite @FumbleFingers - we cant no. But its a bad site

Comment: @mplungjan: I don't get you. You mean ELU is a "bad site" because some of us don't want it to address questions like this one? Given your last comment, you can hardly mean it's a bad site because we allow people to post ungrammatical text with spelling mistakes, incorrect punctuation and capitalisation, etc.

Comment: => bad sight ... I was trying to be funny

Comment: @mplungjan: oic. I can barely handle smileys, so never count on me getting such subtle visual puns! :)

Comment: You have to watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Gv0H-vPoDc).

Comment: @FumbleFingers although admittedly merely hearsay evidence, the fact that i have registered a strong recent increase of this "mistake" suggests that it is more than "bad spelling"

Comment: Getting back to the question, "neologism" is not the term. Variant spelling would be more accurate. The use of word glyphs like _2_ or _&_ instead of spelling out the words they stand for doesn't have a special name, but show up now and then in writing. But since they're intended 2 B pronounced the same, they're not really part of language, just typography, like serifs on letters.

Comment: I suspect that the edit has removed the irony in this post.

Comment: "Is it a passing fad?" Well, without a time machine, that's quite hard to answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's strictly driven by the 140-character limit. Less is more. When texting was pay-per-character, people started looking for ways to save money. This is not new, as telegraphy was the same way; and I have actually held a book with 500 pages of five-character abbreviations for phrases and whole sentences, merely to keep costs down. For instance AABAC BBABD might mean "buy 100 shares" + "next week". Corporations in the telegraphy period often had proprietary telegraph codes, and they were kept quite secret to prevent competitors from learning their intentions. There was also a very short pager-period (before celtels) when families began doing something similar (XXTXX = "come home right now").